# Pytest generate tests in derived classes

Tags: python, inheritance, pytest, code-generation

I need to generate some similar tests according with different data. I tried

```
import pytest


class BaseClass(object):
    data = [1]

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("param1", data)
    def test_something(self, param1):
        assert param1


class Test1(BaseClass):
    data = [2, 3]


class Test2(BaseClass):
    data = [0]
```

but result is

```
collected 2 items

test_of_pytest.py::Test1::test_something[1] PASSED                       [ 50%]
test_of_pytest.py::Test2::test_something[1] PASSED                       [100%]
```

instead of expected something like:

```
collected 3 items

test_of_pytest.py::Test1::test_something[2] PASSED                       [ 33%]
test_of_pytest.py::Test1::test_something[3] PASSED                       [ 66%]
test_of_pytest.py::Test2::test_something[0] FAIL                       [100%]
```

So `@pytest.mark.parametrize` runs only once while reading `BaseClass`.
How to deal with `parametrize`(or some other generator) to behave as i expected?

Comment: `pytest` does not work like that, what you need is fixtures, but even more so why set `data` in the `BaseClass`

Comment: The marker is just another decorator; it will be executed once on import with `Base.data`; the new decorated function is attached to the class and there is nothing left to run in subclasses. This is not specific to `pytest.mark.parametrize` and can be reproduced with any class and any decorated method.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [pytest_generate_tests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html#parametrizing-test-methods-through-per-class-configuration)

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    # called once per each test function
    funcarglist = metafunc.cls.params[metafunc.function.__name__]
    argnames = sorted(funcarglist[0])
    metafunc.parametrize(
    argnames, [[funcargs[name] for name in argnames] for funcargs in funcarglist]
)


class BaseClass(object):
    params = None

    def test_something(self, param):
        assert param


class Test1(BaseClass):
    params = {
        "test_something": [dict(param=2), dict(param=3)]
    }


class Test2(BaseClass):
    params = {
        "test_something": [dict(param=0)]
    }
```